# Matlab: arithmetic operation on columns inside a for loop (simple yet devious!)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector, dimensions

I'm trying to represent a simple matrix m*n (let's assume it has only one row!) such that m1n1 = m1n1^1, m1n2 = m1n1^2, m1n3 = m1n1^3, m1n3 = m1n1^4, ... m1ni = m1n1^i.
In other words, I am trying to iterate over a matrix columns n times to add a new vector(column) at the end such that each of the indices has the same value as the the first vector but raised to the power of its column number n.

This is the original vector:

```
v =
    1.2421
    2.3348
    0.1326
    2.3470
    6.7389
```

and this is v after the third iteration:

```
v = 
    1.2421    1.5429    1.9165
    2.3348    5.4513   12.7277
    0.1326    0.0176    0.0023
    2.3470    5.5084   12.9282
    6.7389   45.4128  306.0329
```

now given that I'm a total noob in Matlab, I really underestimated the difficulty of such a seemingly easy task, that took my almost a day of debugging and surfing the web to find any clue. Here's what I have come up with:

```
rows = 5;
columns = 3;
v = x(1:rows,1);
k = v;
Ncol = ones(rows,1);
extraK = ones(rows,1);

disp(v)

for c = 1:columns
    Ncol = k(:,length(k(1,:))).^c; % a verbose way of selecting the last column only.
    extraK = cat(2,extraK,Ncol);
end

k = cat(2,k,extraK);
disp(extraK(:,2:columns+1)) % to cut off the first column
```

now this code (for some weird reason) work only if rows = 6 or less, and columns = 3 or less.

when rows = 7, this is the output:

```
v = 1.0e+03 *
```

```
0.0012    0.0015    0.0019
0.0023    0.0055    0.0127
0.0001    0.0000    0.0000
0.0023    0.0055    0.0129
0.0067    0.0454    0.3060
0.0037    0.0138    0.0510
0.0119    0.1405    1.6654
```

How could I get it to run on any number of rows and columns?

**Thanks**!

Comment: I'll try this `bsxfun`, and get back to you if it did do the trick.

Comment: actually ... There is a discrepancy between your definition and your announced results! In your `v` with 3 columns, each column seems to be the first `v` to the power of the column index (so 3rd column is v.^3). But in the definition, the third column should be ((v.^2).^3), which would be v.^6. Which one is the right one ?

Comment: yes you're correct @Hoki raising v to the power of n column is what I want. I'll update the post.

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery - ok. so you don't want to reference the last column? You just want to use the original vector and raise it to the `n`th power?  If that's the case, then what I originally had was correct.

Comment: I still can't get it to work though! I keep getting an output I've seen again and again since I started debugging this code.

Comment: the example is correct, and I can assure you that I totally understand this ridiculously simple problem. Let me add some more details from the original work I'm doing now, I'm taking a small substitute vector v from a bigger one x and try to apply the simple power operation on every index of v as described. The reason is that I got unexpected results when I was working with x, and I decided to reduce the problem to smaller size so I could wrap my head around it, and it all went down to this puzzling 6*3 matrix!!

Comment: Then why don't you give me an example of what you **expect** to get in comparison to what you are getting with your code?  I don't see that in your problem statement except when `n=3`.  Show us a failure case.

Comment: ok now it seems to me, the code is correct, but their is something wrong with the format, the output should be double! (hmmm, somebody's going to through something at somebody else now, maybe!!)

Comment: I changed the format to bank so you can see the significant digits. Type in format short to reset the formatting. Mayhap you should actually read the code before copying and pasting.

Comment: Actually `format longG` was precisely what I wasted my day for. Thanks a lot @rayryeng, God bless you man, GOD bless you.

Comment: No problem boss.  Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. I'm not sure as to why you are defining `d = 3;`.  This is just nitpicking, but you can remove that from your code safely.
2. You are not doing the power operation properly.  Specifically, look at this statement:

   ```
   Ncol = k(:,length(k(1,:))).^c; % a verbose way of selecting the last column only.
   ```

   You are selectively choosing the last column, which is great, but you are not applying the power operation properly.  If I understand your statement, you wish to take the **original** vector, and perform a power operation to the power of `n`, where `n` is the current iteration.  Therefore, you really just need to do this:

   ```
   Ncol = k.^c;
   ```

   Once you replace `Ncol` with the above line, the code should now work.  I also noticed that you crop out the first column of your result.  The reason why you are getting duplicate columns is because your `for` loop starts from `c = 1`.  Since you have already computed `v.^1 = v`, you can just start your loop at `c = 2`.  Change your loop starting point to `c = 2`, and you can get rid of the removal of the first column.

---

However, I'm going to do this in an alternative way in one line of code.  Before we do this, let's go through the theory of what you're trying to do.

Given a vector `v` that is `m` elements long stored in a `m x 1` vector, what you want is to have a matrix of size `m x n`, where `n` is the desired number of columns, and for each column starting from left to right, you wish to take `v` to the `n`<sup>th</sup> power.

Therefore, given your example from your third "iteration", the first column represents `v`, the second column represents `v.^2`, and the third column represents `v.^3`.

---

I'm going to introduce you to the power of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).  `bsxfun` stands for **B**inary **S**ingleton E**X**pansion function.  What `bsxfun` does is that if you have two inputs where either or both inputs has a singleton dimension, or if either of both inputs has **only** one dimension which has value of 1, each input is replicated in their singleton dimensions to match the size of the other input, and then an element-wise operation is applied to these inputs together to produce your output.

For example, if we had two vectors like so:

```
A = [1 2 3]

B = [1
     2
     3]
```

Note that one of them is a row vector, and the other is a column vector.  `bsxfun` would see that `A` and `B` both have singleton dimensions, where `A` has a singleton dimension being the number of rows being 1, and `B` having a singleton dimension which is the number of columns being 1.  Therefore, we would duplicate `B` as many columns as there are in `A` and duplicate `A` for as many rows as there are in `B`, and we actually get:

```
A = [1 2 3
     1 2 3
     1 2 3]

B = [1 1 1
     2 2 2
     3 3 3]
```

Once we have these two matrices, you can apply any element wise operations to these matrices to get your output.  For example, you could add, subtract, take the power or do an element wise multiplication or division.

---

Now, how this scenario applies to your problem is the following.  What you are doing is you have a vector `v`, and you will have a **matrix** of powers like so:

```
M = [1 2 3 ... n
     1 2 3 ... n
     ...........
     ...........
     1 2 3 ... n]
```

Essentially, we will have a column of 1s, followed by a column of 2s, up to as many columns as you want `n`.  We would apply `bsxfun` on the vector `v` which is a column vector, and another vector that is only a **single row** of values from 1 up to `n`.  You would apply the power operation to achieve your result.  Therefore, you can conveniently calculate your output by doing:

```
columns = 3;
out = bsxfun(@power, v, 1:columns);
```

Let's try a few examples given your vector `v`:

```
>> v = [1.2421; 2.3348; 0.1326; 2.3470; 6.7389];
>> columns = 3;
>> out = bsxfun(@power, v, 1:columns)

out =

    1.2421    1.5428    1.9163
    2.3348    5.4513   12.7277
    0.1326    0.0176    0.0023
    2.3470    5.5084   12.9282
    6.7389   45.4128  306.0321

>> columns = 7;
>> format bank
>> out = bsxfun(@power, v, 1:columns)

out =

  Columns 1 through 5

          1.24          1.54          1.92          2.38          2.96
          2.33          5.45         12.73         29.72         69.38
          0.13          0.02          0.00          0.00          0.00
          2.35          5.51         12.93         30.34         71.21
          6.74         45.41        306.03       2062.32      13897.77

  Columns 6 through 7

          3.67          4.56
        161.99        378.22
          0.00          0.00
        167.14        392.28
      93655.67     631136.19
```

Note that for setting the columns to 3, we get what we see in your post.  For pushing the columns up to 7, I had to change the way the numbers were presented so you can see the numbers clearly.  Not doing this would put this into exponential form, and there were a lot of zeroes that followed the significant digits.

---

Good luck!

Comment: man you're so fast at typing ... I was preparing exactly the same answer (with less explanation even) and by the time i'm done I see your answer is there since ages ago !! well done anyway.

Comment: yes you're right, I should've explained what is `v = x(1:rows,1);` but regardless, the value of v is in the example I gave before. Also you're right about `d = 3;` it just a typo, as I actually just reduced my original code to this sample code that capture exactly my problem. It has been a long long day man!

Comment: Well apparently the `bsxfun` function has that same original problem that it breaks if the number of rows is more than 6, or the number of columns is more than 3!!! also your revision of my code seems to have the exact same issue. Nothing beyond 6-by-3 matrix!!!

Answer (score 2):

When computing cumulative powers you can *reuse previous results*: for scalar `x` and `n`, `x.^n` is equal to `x * x.^(n-1)`, where `x.^(n-1)` has been already obtained. This may be *more efficient* than computing each power independently, because multiplication is faster than power.

Let `N` be the maximum exponent desired. To use the described approach, the column vector `v` is repeated `N` times horizontally  ([`repmat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)), and then a cumulative product is applied along each row ([`cumprod`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html)):

```
v =[1.2421; 2.3348; 0.1326; 2.3470; 6.7389]; %// data. Column vector
N = 3; %// maximum exponent
result = cumprod(repmat(v, 1, N), 2);
```

Comment: This's a handy practice, I'll try to use in the future. Thanks!